# YAGO class hirearchy in DBpedia

Tags: dbpedia

What file in DBpedia (3.7) contains the YAGO class hierarchy. I can find references to a file called `yago-class-hierarchy_en.nt` on some forums, but cannot find it under: http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.7/

Answer (score 1):

This would be http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.7/links/yago_links.nt.bz2, the only problem is that the http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf property is misspelled as http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#suBClassOf.